# ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library definition. Chainlink NFT Tutorial

Tags: chainlink

working through a [Chainlink Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EzZEx0lumr0) but I'm stuck in 19:09.

Running:

```
truffle compile
```

I get the following error:

```sh
░▒▓    ~/De/dynamicNFT  on   main !2 ?3 ▓▒░ truffle compile❯ truffle compile

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol
> Compiling ./contracts/NFTSimple.sol
> Compiling ./contracts/RandomNumberConsumer.sol
> Compiling ./contracts/test/MockV3Aggregator.sol
> Compiling ./contracts/test/VRFCoordinatorMock.sol
> Compiling @chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol
> Compiling @chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/LinkTokenInterface.sol
> Compiling @chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/tests/MockV3Aggregator.sol
> Compiling @chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/tests/VRFCoordinatorMock.sol

@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol:103:1: ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library definition.
abstract contract VRFConsumerBase is VRFRequestIDBase {
^------^
,@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/tests/MockV3Aggregator.sol:15:27: ParserError: Expected identifier but got reserved keyword 'override'
  uint256 constant public override version = 0;
                          ^------^
,project:/contracts/NFTSimple.sol:3:1: ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Full.sol" not found
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Full.sol";
^-----------------------------------------------------------^
,project:/contracts/NFTSimple.sol:4:1: ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Mintable.sol" not found
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Mintable.sol";
^---------------------------------------------------------------^
,project:/contracts/RandomNumberConsumer.sol:51:86: ParserError: Expected '{' but got reserved keyword 'override'
    function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 /* requestId */, uint256 randomness) internal override {
                                                                                     ^------^

Compilation failed. See above.
Truffle v5.4.10 (core: 5.4.10)
Node v16.9.1
```

````
❯ ls
LICENSE            package-lock.json
README.md        package.json
contracts        scripts
migrations        test
node_modules        truffle-config.js
░▒▓    ~/De/dynamicNFT  on   main !2 ?3 ▓▒░```
````

Comment: Thanks so much for making this issue. Does this help you at all? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/66148/57451

It's likely you missed some part of the code. What happens when you clone the repo and try to compile from scratch?

Comment: ```❯ git clone https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/dungeons-and-dragons-nft.git
❯ cd dungeons-and-dragons-nft
❯ npm i
❯ truffle compile
```
worked, guess my problem when following along or something outdated. ok thanks!